# SQL One to Many with possible UNION

Tags: php, sql, angularjs, json

I have a question about a query I am constructing and I would like to do it all in an SQL statement.

So, I have one table of data like this:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| pid | did | src | val |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|   1 |   1 | lab |   0 |
|   1 |   1 | lab |   1 |
|   2 |   3 | pl  |   1 |
|   1 |   1 | pl  |   1 |
|   2 |   1 | med |   1 |
|   1 |   1 | med |   1 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

There is an ID column (pid), and a disease column (did), and a source (src) column and a value (val) column.  The disease column has also a normalized table I created like this:

```
+-----+-----------------+
| did |      name       |
+-----+-----------------+
|   1 | Lung Cancer     |
|   2 | Alcoholism      |
|   3 | Obesity         |
|   4 | Diabetes        |
|   5 | Viral Infection |
+-----+-----------------+
```

The real trick here is that I need to do a query that results in a table that produces a new table that shows each pid (ID), and the associated text name for the disease (did) which is a probably a JOIN with the normalized table.

The tricky part is that for each ID, I need to count the occurrences of EACH of the (3) possible sources (src), so there will be maybe 5-10 occurences of an ID of 1, and each one of these will have a src associated: either MED, LAB, or PL.  I need to count these up per record and display in a table like this below.

```
+-----+------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------+
| pid |      Lung Cancer       |        Alcoholism        |       Obesity              
+-----+------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------+
|   1 | Yes                    | Maybe                    | No                   |
|     | (med: 2, lab: 1, pl:1) | (med: 0, lab: 1, pl:1)   | (med:0, lab:0, pl:0) |
+-----+------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------+
```

So there may be 5-10 rows with and ID of 1, and for each row, there will be a src (source) assigned which will be one of three values (lab, pl, med) and these will have a value of 0 zero or 1 one.

In the end there will be a count, and basically three states are arrived at (Yes) they have a disease, (All 1's or above for each source), or zero's for two, but one has 1 or more (maybe), or all zeros, (no)

I am not sure all of this can be accomplished with a SQL statement... or I can use JOIN/UNION or some combination to build a new table and place all the values, and then json_encode it (I'm using PHP), and then use Angular to sort through the src values and do the computations and show a bootstrap button for "Yes", "No" or "Maybe"

Thanks for you guys help!  This is quite a puzzling SQL statement, or at least I think so.

Comment: which RDBMS? mysql? sql-server? oracle?  what have you tried?  You seem to be looking for a pivot situation more than likely using conditional aggregation.

Comment: In order for this to work all in SQL, you would likely need a correlated sub-query for each of the different types of src to get their totals. This is typically the only way to get one or more rows into multiple columns in the result. It would be easier to just join the two tables with grouping and summing and then translate the rows to columns in php.

Comment: You get most of the way there with a GROUP BY.  The actual presentation of the data can be handled using a small amount of procedural code in either PHP or angular where you would utilize an HTML table which is valid for a table of medical data.   You are going to select *, SUM(val) as val FROM pidTable JOIN didTABLE ON didTable.did = pidTable.did GROUP BY pid, didTable.did, src

Comment: @gview -- that makes no sense what does HTML have to do with this question?

Comment: @Hogan, I'm advising to present the final output using HTML rather than trying to create a pseudo table in SQL.  Either PHP or Angular is where the presentation/html output should be done.  The user mentioned the use of both of these in the question -- I didn't suggest them.

Comment: Thanks guys for your input...  Sorry, the RDBMS is MySQL.  It's easy enough to do an inner join do get the disease number replaced with the name.

Comment: I was thinking it might be a many to many relationship... So there are multiple PID's... i.e. 1,2,3,4 etc... and each PID will have 3 sources, either PL, MED, or LAB, and of course each time, each 3 sources would be 0 or 1.  I mentioned angular... because basically my program has angular on the front end and just calls an $http in the scope and hits a PHP file that sends an SQL query to MySQL and then json_encodes it.  Then with angular I use ui.grid to display the table... but the confusion is whether SQL can do all this, and I just kick down the new table and have angular render it....

Comment: Yes, I basically gave you the mysql syntax.  I would suggest using aliases for the join clause.  You didn't give us actual table names, so I had to use ones I inferred.

Comment: yeah, the table names for the main one is "person_disease", and the normalized one with the long names of diseases is "disease"  It's kinda like you would have to have 3 sub queries to add up each occurence for MED, PL, and LAB in EACH ID or EACH DISEASE.  this is the best description, but I have no idea how to attack i... could you guys maybe post some sample code that might give a hint?  Thanks a bunch guys!

Comment: @StaceyYates - this is one query with a sub-query and you don't need the disease name table -- ids are unique just group by them.

Comment: Yes gview, I was thinking this as well.  I wanted to be elegant and just write an SQl statement that did it all...or get as much of it as possible into a pseudo table so I can make angular/php do as little work as possible to layout the table... but the calculations for "Yes", "No" or "Maybe" may just not be possible in SQL.  The big question is just the sample code to get the SQL and maybe I will have to process some in Angular/PHP.  There's probably dozens of ways to do it and in a real world situation with millions of records, that's when the big talk would be interesting to have. (speed)

Comment: Stacey Yates: essentially when you are summarizing data, you are going to scan the entire table for this report.  The more rows the longer it will take.  For your joins, you should simply have the appropriate indexes on your keys and foreign keys.  For mysql typically people use Innodb engine, which will allow you to add foreign key constraint statements that will also build the FK indexes at declaration.

Comment: @gview - how was I being rude?  I know sql and I think it is easier to do in sql and you know PHP and think it is easier to do in PHP.  This was my point.  There is nothing about the nature of the problem that is better for one or the other and the OP asked for SQL.

Comment: @Hogan, well let's see: first off I provided a mysql flavored query, and you then made the idiotic statement "that is because you don't know sql".  I am well aware of what can be done using the procedural constructs and string manipulation functions in SQL.  You looked at this question as a puzzle to be solved apparently.  I didn't.  Enuff said.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy, just take it in steps.. first the roll up the src:

```
SELECT pid, did, 
       sum(CASE WHEN src='med' THEN val ELSE O END) AS med,
       sum(CASE WHEN src='lab' THEN val ELSE O END) AS lab,
       sum(CASE WHEN src='pl' THEN val ELSE O END) AS pl
FROM table_of_data
GROUP BY pid, did
```

Now pull into columns by did

```
SELECT pid,
       max(CASE WHEN did=1 THEN '(med:'|| CAST(med as varchar(5)) ||
                            ', lab:'|| CASE(lab as varchar(5)) ||
                            ', pl:' || CAST(pl as varhcar(5)) || ')' 
                       ELSE null END) AS Lung_Cancer,  
       max(CASE WHEN did=2 THEN '(med:'|| CAST(med as varchar(5)) ||
                            ', lab:'|| CASE(lab as varchar(5)) ||
                            ', pl:' || CAST(pl as varhcar(5)) || ')' 
                       ELSE null END) AS Alcoholism,  
       max(CASE WHEN did=3 THEN '(med:'|| CAST(med as varchar(5)) ||
                            ', lab:'|| CASE(lab as varchar(5)) ||
                            ', pl:' || CAST(pl as varhcar(5)) || ')' 
                       ELSE null END) AS Obesity,  
       max(CASE WHEN did=4 THEN '(med:'|| CAST(med as varchar(5)) ||
                            ', lab:'|| CASE(lab as varchar(5)) ||
                            ', pl:' || CAST(pl as varhcar(5)) || ')' 
                       ELSE null END) AS Diabetes,  
       max(CASE WHEN did=5 THEN '(med:'|| CAST(med as varchar(5)) ||
                            ', lab:'|| CASE(lab as varchar(5)) ||
                            ', pl:' || CAST(pl as varhcar(5)) || ')' 
                       ELSE null END) AS Viral_Infection,  
FROM prior_result
GROUP BY pid
```

To get the yes no maybe use a case from the prior result

```
SELECT pid, did,
       CASE WHEN med+lab+pl > 3 THEN 'Yes'
            WHEN med+lab+pl = 0 THEN 'No'
            ELSE 'Maybe' END AND as have_it
FROM prior_result
```

No problem ... put it all together and you get

```
SELECT pid,
       max(CASE WHEN did=1 THEN '(med:'|| CAST(med as varchar(5)) ||
                            ', lab:'|| CASE(lab as varchar(5)) ||
                            ', pl:' || CAST(pl as varhcar(5)) || ')' 
                       ELSE null END) AS Lung_Cancer,  
       max(CASE WHEN did=1 THEN
                             CASE WHEN med+lab+pl > 3 THEN 'Yes'
                                  WHEN med+lab+pl = 0 THEN 'No'
                                  ELSE 'Maybe'
                              END
                            ELSE null END) AS Have_Lung_Cancer,  

       max(CASE WHEN did=2 THEN '(med:'|| CAST(med as varchar(5)) ||
                            ', lab:'|| CASE(lab as varchar(5)) ||
                            ', pl:' || CAST(pl as varhcar(5)) || ')' 
                       ELSE null END) AS Alcoholism,  
       max(CASE WHEN did=2 THEN
                             CASE WHEN med+lab+pl > 3 THEN 'Yes'
                                  WHEN med+lab+pl = 0 THEN 'No'
                                  ELSE 'Maybe'
                              END
                            ELSE null END) AS Have_Alcoholism,  

       max(CASE WHEN did=3 THEN '(med:'|| CAST(med as varchar(5)) ||
                            ', lab:'|| CASE(lab as varchar(5)) ||
                            ', pl:' || CAST(pl as varhcar(5)) || ')' 
                       ELSE null END) AS Obesity,  
       max(CASE WHEN did=3 THEN
                             CASE WHEN med+lab+pl > 3 THEN 'Yes'
                                  WHEN med+lab+pl = 0 THEN 'No'
                                  ELSE 'Maybe'
                              END
                            ELSE null END) AS Have_Obesity,  

       max(CASE WHEN did=4 THEN '(med:'|| CAST(med as varchar(5)) ||
                            ', lab:'|| CASE(lab as varchar(5)) ||
                            ', pl:' || CAST(pl as varhcar(5)) || ')' 
                       ELSE null END) AS Diabetes,  
       max(CASE WHEN did=4 THEN
                             CASE WHEN med+lab+pl > 3 THEN 'Yes'
                                  WHEN med+lab+pl = 0 THEN 'No'
                                  ELSE 'Maybe'
                              END
                            ELSE null END) AS Have_Diabetes,  

       max(CASE WHEN did=5 THEN '(med:'|| CAST(med as varchar(5)) ||
                            ', lab:'|| CASE(lab as varchar(5)) ||
                            ', pl:' || CAST(pl as varhcar(5)) || ')' 
                       ELSE null END) AS Viral_Infection,  
       max(CASE WHEN did=5 THEN
                             CASE WHEN med+lab+pl > 3 THEN 'Yes'
                                  WHEN med+lab+pl = 0 THEN 'No'
                                  ELSE 'Maybe'
                              END
                            ELSE null END) AS Have_Viral_Infection,  

FROM (
  SELECT pid, did, 
       sum(CASE WHEN src='med' THEN val ELSE O END) AS med,
       sum(CASE WHEN src='lab' THEN val ELSE O END) AS lab,
       sum(CASE WHEN src='pl' THEN val ELSE O END) AS pl
  FROM table_of_data
  GROUP BY pid, did
) sub
GROUP BY pid
```

Comment: And every time a new disease or source gets added the SQL code needs to be changed.  Not very relational, but certainly does show that if you want to use lots of SQL functions you can do about anything.

Comment: You guys are f**king geniuses. This is a great start.  Thanks for framing this for me.  I will try it out and maybe check back later.  Anyone else who has ideas also post.  I learn a ton from you guys.

Comment: @gview it is very relevant to that too.... if you want to make it work dynamically you would have to have dynamic sql and the dynamic sql to generate would look like this -- so it is the first step.

Comment: Yeah, Matt I have no idea how you would do the YES, NO, MAYBE eval. perhaps iterate though the json on the front end with angular and display a bootstrap button class for a red, yellow, green button or similar...but again, with elegance, if you were to do that will tens of millions of records....maybe not a good idea.

Comment: @matt -- I think it will be just one case statement... I have to re-read those requirements

Comment: This is why us front end devs are in awe of you back end guys.  Could guys in the SQL show me how to use the code with the database name if the database name is "person_disease", and the normalization table is "disease"   Would it be SELECT pid FROM person_disease, and then the MAX(Case stuff?

Comment: @Hogan,  I personally would not solve a problem like this in this way, because Stacey did state in the original question that there will be a web UI presenting this data.  A robust and flexible solution that doesn't mangle the data into a near final form would be very typical and more robust in my experience.  But I credit you with providing an exact solution, and furthermore I appreciate the way you built up the answer in stages to help teach what you were doing.  Please keep it civil and productive.

Comment: @StaceyYates - I added in the code to do the yes, no, maybe.  Hard to tell exactly if it would work because your requirements are vague.  It may need to be slightly different but I think this shows you the way.  Don't be in awe, learn and make others in awe of you.

Comment: Just a note you could just determine your YES NO MAYBE on your inner grouped by did query CASE WHEN SUM(val) > 2 THEN 'Yes' etc. it would save you a bunch of typing on your query and if you build the med/lab string there too it will be less typing as well when you pivot

Comment: @Matt -- these things require mysql - mine works with all platforms.  I didn't know the platform when I wrote it.  I also think this is clear to a beginner -- doing 5 things at once often will be hard to grok.

Comment: @Hogan I apologize if I somehow offended I was offering a suggestion for consolidating code so you didn't have to re-write a bunch of the same stuff. I put an answer in to show you and others what I meant by that while still giving you the credit on the answer.  My answer was tested on mysql and sql-server and I am pretty sure is ANSI compliant so I think we are okay there..  anyway, I agree helping a beginner understand the steps and how you presented was a great way of showing the logic cheers.

Comment: @Matt - your answer is excellent - I was reading the answer by Thorsten Kettner when I said it was mysql only.

Answer (score 0):

And seeing you may need to figure all of this out dynamically at some point here is a way to get to your results then pivot with a little less typing than @hogan's answer but it is based on his answer.

```
SELECT
    d.pid
    ,COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN d.did = 1 THEN colString END),'No (med:0 lab:0 pl:0)') as Lung_Cancer
    ,COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN d.did = 2 THEN colString END),'No (med:0 lab:0 pl:0)') as Alcoholism
    ,COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN d.did = 3 THEN colString END),'No (med:0 lab:0 pl:0)') as Obesity
FROM
    (
     SELECT pid, did, 
          CONCAT(CASE
             WHEN SUM(Val) > 2 THEN 'Yes'
             WHEN SUM(Val) > 1 THEN 'Maybe'
             ELSE 'No'
          End
          ,' (med:'
          ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN src='med' THEN val ELSE 0 END) AS CHAR(5))
          ,' lab:'
          ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN src='lab' THEN val ELSE 0 END) AS CHAR(5))
          ,' pl:'
          ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN src='pl' THEN val ELSE 0 END) AS CHAR(5))
          ,')') as colString

     FROM TableP
     GROUP BY pid, did
    ) d
GROUP BY
    d.pid
```

note the use of COALESCE deals with when there are no values for a PID for a particular disease. sql fiddle of it: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44ac9/11

And just to show you it can all be done without sub query:

```
SELECT
    pid
    ,CONCAT(CASE
       WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN did = 1 THEN val ELSE 0 END) > 2 THEN 'Yes'
       WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN did = 1 THEN val ELSE 0 END) > 1 THEN 'Maybe'
       ELSE 'No'
    END
    , ' (med:'
    ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN did = 1 and src = 'med' THEN val ELSE 0 END) AS CHAR(5))
    , ', lab:'
    ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN did = 1 and src = 'lab' THEN val ELSE 0 END) AS CHAR(5))
    , ', pl:'
    ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN did = 1 and src = 'pl' THEN val ELSE 0 END) AS CHAR(5))
    ,')' ) AS Lung_Cancer

    .......repeat per disease

FROM
    table_of_data
GROUP BY
    pid
```

SQL fiddle of this technique http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44ac9/13

Comment: Thank you everyone for your altruism and willingness to suggest things. It gave me some great ideas for my project!

Answer (score 0):

As you also have a certain amount of valid sources, you should have a table for them, too:

```
+-----+-----+
| src | pos |
+-----+-----+
| lab | 2   |
| med | 1   |
| pl  | 3   |
+-----+-----+
```

(The column `pos` says at which position in the results you want the source shown.)

Then cross join diseases and sources to get all combinations. Outer join the data table for the desired pid and count per desease and source. The rest is mainly string concatenation:

```
set @pid = 1;

select
  pid, 
  name, 
  concat
  (
    case when count(sumval) <> count(*) then 'Maybe'
         when min(sumval) > 0 then 'Yes' 
         when max(sumval) = 0 then 'No'
         else 'Maybe'
    end,
    ' (',
    group_concat(concat(src, ': ', coalesce(sumval, '?')) order by pos separator ', '),
    ')'
  ) as result
from
(
  select @pid as pid, d.*, s.*, sum(data.val) as sumval 
  from desease d
  cross join source s
  left join data on  data.did = d.did
                 and data.src = s.src 
                 and data.pid = @pid
  group by d.did, s.src
) sumvals
group by did
having count(sumval) > 0;
```

This gives you rows such as:

```
+-----+-----------------+-------------------------------+
| pid | name            | result                        |
+-----+-----------------+-------------------------------+
| 1   | Lung Cancer     | Yes (med: 2, lab: 1, pl: 1)   |
| 1   | Alcoholism      | Maybe (med: 0, lab: 1, pl: 1) |
| 1   | Obesity         | No (med: 0, lab: 0, pl: 0)    |
+-----+-----------------+-------------------------------+
```

When there is no entry for a pid, desease and source we don't know whether the desease applies or not. `sumval` is null in this case. If there is not even one entry for a desease then we just don't show it at all (see the `having` clause). Otherwise, if there is at least one source given and another missing we conclude 'Maybe'.

Here is the SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2ac29/1

It is the task of your GUI layer to care about the layout (in your case: show the results in columns).

Comment: @Matt: You are right. I treated non-existent entries as if they existed with a zero val. This is wrong of course and could not even be handled thoroughly  in GUI anymore (as then we wouldn't know whether zero means zero or no data). I've corrected my answer, so a desease is not shown now when there is no data on it for a pid, and 'Maybe' is shown when sources for a desease are incomplete.